# How can I reuse library declarations in Gradle Kotlin DSL?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, dependency-management

**Background:**

We are trying to migrate to Gradle's Kotlin DSL, primarily for the additional type safety.

Some of our library definitions are quite large (20+ `exclude` calls in some extreme cases) so we currently have a giant `dependencies.gradle` Groovy script which declares a giant map of all libraries, which can then be used like `libraries.blah`. I'm trying to come up with a working way to do the same in Kotlin.

**Investigation:**

Dependency *constraints* (`java-platform` plugin) allow centralising the version number for the dependency, but that does nothing for the exclusions, and the exclusions are most of the problem in our case. (I'm sure we will eventually use `java-platform` at some point too.)

The most elegant-looking solution I found was in [this one blog post which suggests declaring Kotlin objects](https://proandroiddev.com/avoid-repetitive-dependency-declarations-with-gradle-kotlin-dsl-97c904704727), like this:

```kotlin
object Libraries {
    val guava = "..."
}
```

You can then *supposedly* use the object like `Libraries.guava`. But this doesn't actually work, at least in Gradle 6.9.1, because of [an issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/18706) [in Kotlin itself](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-32410). (I'm assuming that it worked on some older version and got broken by a Kotlin compiler upgrade.)

The workaround specified on the ticket comes out like:

```kotlin
class Libraries(dependencies: DependencyHandler) {
    val guava = dependencies.create(...)
}

val libraries by project.extra { Libraries(dependencies) }
```

This gets me closer to a working solution in that my `dependencies.gradle.kts` file now compiles, but I still can't find a way to use the `Libraries` class I've defined. If you do this:

```kotlin
val libraries: Libraries by project.extra
```

Kotlin complains that `Libraries` is not defined. So it's as if one build script can't even export classes for another build script to use.

**More Context**

The actual project structure is quite complex, and looks a bit like this:

```
─ repo root
  ├─ mainproject1
  │  ├─ subproject11
  │  │  └─ build.gradle.kts
  │  ├─ subproject12
  │  │  └─ build.gradle.kts
  │  ├─ build.gradle.kts (references dependencies.gradle.kts)
  │  └─ settings.gradle.kts
  ├─ mainproject2
  │  ├─ subproject21
  │  │  └─ build.gradle.kts
  │  ├─ subproject22
  │  │  └─ build.gradle.kts
  │  ├─ build.gradle.kts (references dependencies.gradle.kts)
  │  └─ settings.gradle.kts
  └─ shared
     └─ gradle
        └─ dependencies.gradle.kts
```

**Question:**

How are other people with enormous builds with >100 dependencies solving this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Workaround: use [`buildSrc`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:build_sources) to instantiate `Libraries` object.

1. Create the following directories structure:

```
.
├── buildSrc
│   ├── build.gradle.kts
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── kotlin
│               └── Libraries.kt
├── settings.gradle.kts
└── build.gradle.kts
```

2. `buildSrc/build.gradle.kts` is minimalistic:

```kotlin
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

3. `Libraries.kt`:

```kotlin
object Libraries {
    const val guava = "com.google.guava:guava:31.0.1-jre"
}
```

4. Usage (root `build.gradle.kts`):

```kotlin
plugins {
    `java-library`
}

dependencies {
    implementation(Libraries.guava)
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: Tricky to do, because we also have multiple projects which import the same shared gradle file. I guess to use `buildSrc` we'd have to either symlink `buildSrc` for all the projects to the same destination, or modify `buildSrc/build.gradle.kts` to link out to a shared source directory (which breaks IDEA for that project - one of our projects does this and IDEA complains if you try to build it - but for that project we had no choice because the project was a gradle plugin which we wanted applied to itself!)

Comment: For multi-project builds `buildSrc` placed in the root project directory will be applied to all sub-projects. If you need to share some logic across several _independent_ projects, then it needs to be extracted into the [standalone Gradle plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:custom_plugins_standalone_project) (and applied to these projects). Note, that classes (and extension methods) defined in the plugin (unlike in buildSrc) won't be added into the build script classpath, so this use-case would require a different approach.

Comment: We do have multiple “independent” projects. They’re in the same repo though so I can have them all reference a build plugin stored in a sibling directory. I am finding it challenging to even declare this Libraries object correctly because IDEA in particular refuses to acknowledge gradle scripts as part of the build _until they compile_, which is a bit of a catch-22 that makes it hard to figure out what the problem is until you accidentally fix it.